# Saving edits slowing down (QGIS 2.01)

Tags: qgis, editing

QGIS 2.01 on Windows 8

I have a polygon layer which I edit in QGIS 2.01. Editing (cutting, deleting, editing new polygons with attributes) works fine. I am saving the changes after every edit or so while in edit session. Then after editing away for some time (10 Min) and saving 4-5 edits the saving process becomes unbearably slow and it takes between 1 and 7 (!) minutes to save the changes. Mouse cursor is going crazy, CPU and ram are maxing out. Then after the edits are finally saved, ending the edit session again takes several minutes. I tried the dataset with SQLite and shp, both delivered the same experience.

Any clues why this might be the case? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is due to an issue with the bugs in some of the plugins installed. Try to disable your plugins and see if it works for you. Try disabling 'Rectangles Oval Digitizing' and 'digitizing tools' plugins first.

Comment: This seems to have done the trick. I had the plugin "Digitizing Tools" on and after deactivating it, things run a lot smoother. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have an antivirus software? Then try to disable it, or set a antivirus scanning exception for your storage folder.

Please, check also if the `Disk write caching` is enabled for your hard drive. See **[this](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/enable-disable-disk-write-caching-windows-7-8)** link to learn how to enable it.