# QGIS 2.14.3 very slow when saving edits on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: qgis, editing

QGIS 2.14.3 "Essen" is really very slow when saving edits on a single layer (point features) on Ubuntu 16.04 64 bits.

There is only about 100 points in this layer. In editing mode, when saving, it takes about 15-20min (grayed QGIS windows during this time).
CPU (Athlon II X4 640) is always at 100% activity during this time.
Data are stored locally. There is no connection to any network.

What is the cause and how to fix it?

Comment: are you using Shapefiles, PostGIS, etc.?

Comment: Have you installed some digitizing plugins? They might slow down the saving even when you did not use them at all. It might help uninstalling them when they are not needed. See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85483/saving-edits-slowing-down-qgis-2-01 and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119457/qgis-freezes-after-making-and-saving-many-edits-to-a-layer